# Splitting rational bezier

Tags: math, graphics, language-agnostic, bezier

According to someone a rational bezier can be split by projecting its control points from 2d to 3d (or from 3d to 4d and so on), splitting the resulting non-rational curve with De Casteljau, and then projecting the two curves back to 2d which makes them rational again.

I have this Shadertoy prototype where I tried to put the weights directly in place of the z value, before realizing there would need to be some kind of transformation on the xy coordinates for the De Casteljau calculated midpoint (m) to align with the weighted curve. A projection matrix can have a field of view and an aspect ratio attribute from what I've seen.

What kind of matrix do I need to get the points and weights to align correctly, and what should I do with the weights to begin with to turn them into z coordinates?

```
vec3[6] split(float[3] r, vec2[3] p, float t)
{
    vec3 a = vec3(p[0],r[0]);
    vec3 b = vec3(p[1],r[1]);
    vec3 c = vec3(p[2],r[2]);
    vec3 ab = mix(a, b, t);
    vec3 bc = mix(b, c, t);
    vec3 m = mix(ab, bc, t);
    
    vec3[3] l = vec3[3](a,ab,m);
    vec3[3] R = vec3[3](m,bc,c);
    return vec3[6](l[0],l[1],l[2],R[0],R[1],R[2]);
}
```

Comment: Do you have a source to the explanation where you got this fact from? I am trying to understand your problem description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In degree 2, for example, a Bezier is f(t) = (1-t)<sup>2</sup>P<sub>0</sub> + 2t(1-t)P<sub>1</sub> + t<sup>2</sup>P<sub>2</sub>

A rational Bezier is (1-t)<sup>2</sup>P<sub>0</sub>w<sub>0</sub> + 2t(1-t)P<sub>1</sub>w<sub>1</sub> + t<sup>2</sup>P<sub>2</sub>w<sub>2</sub> / (1-t)<sup>2</sup>w<sub>0</sub> + 2t(1-t)w<sub>1</sub> + t<sup>2</sup>w<sub>2</sub>

If your perspective transform maps (x,y,z) to (x/z, y/z), then you can move the weights directly into the z coordinate to get the correct denominator, but you *also* have to multiply the corresponding points to make the new points map to the same (x,y).

When you do both, it simplifies, and your new points are:

P<sub>0</sub>' = w<sub>0</sub>(P<sub>0</sub>,1)

P<sub>1</sub>' = w<sub>1</sub>(P<sub>1</sub>,1)

P<sub>2</sub>' = w<sub>2</sub>(P<sub>2</sub>,1)

The regular 3D Bezier will then map to the same (x,y) curve under perspective transformation:

f(t) = (1-t)<sup>2</sup>P<sub>0</sub>' + 2t(1-t)P<sub>1</sub>' + t<sup>2</sup>P<sub>2</sub>'